# Yibum and Chalitzah: stringency or leniency?

Tags: marriage, lomdus, yibbum-chalitza-levirate, masechet-yevamot

In [*Yevamoth* 8a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=14&daf=8&format=pdf), we discuss a group of women (enumerated in *mishna* 1:1) with whom neither *yibum* (levirate marriage) nor *chalitzah* (the rejection of levirate marriage) takes place.

According to the *gemara*, there are two places in *Torah* whence we can learn about levirate marriage: a man's brother's wife and a man's wife's sister.  The former is a situation in which a man A performs either *yibum* or *chalitzah* with his brother B's wife when B dies without children (where normally a man's brother's wife is forbidden to him); the latter is that a man may not perform *yibum* or *chalitzah* with the sister of his wife.

Up to this point, the *gemara* has compared the group of women (enumerated in the first *mishna*) with a man's wife's sister (and hence they are exempt from *yibum* and *chalitzah*).  The *gemara* now asks why we don't compare this group to a man's brother's wife, and hence permit *yibum* and *chalitzah* with them.  The first answer given reads as follows.

> אמר ליה רב אחא מדפתי לרבינא מכדי כל עריות איכא לאקושינהו לאשת אח ואיכא
>   לאקושינהו לאחות אשה מאי חזית דאקשת לאחות אשה אקשינהו לאשת אח איבעית
>   אימא לקולא וחומרא לחומרא מקשינן
>
> Said R. Aha of Difti to Rabina: Consider! All forbidden relatives
>   might be compared to a brother's wife and might equally be compared to
>   a wife's sister, what reason do you see for comparing them to a wife's
>   sister? Compare them rather to a brother's wife! — If you wish I might
>   say: When a comparison may be made for increasing as well as for
>   decreasing restrictions, that for increasing restrictions must be
>   preferred. [translation from [here](http://halakhah.com/yebamoth/yebamoth_8.html)]

The *gemara* answers that permitting *yibum* would be a leniency, since we would be permitting a marriage where normally (outside of a *yibum* situation) it would be forbidden.  The *gemara* asserts that we prefer not to do that if there is a stringency that could be applied instead.

**My question: is this stringency not a stringency that might lead to a leniency (חומרא דאתי לידי קולא)? Should we not also require *chalitzah* as a stringency before the woman marries someone else?**

Consider, for example, the case of two brothers A and B, where A is married to X, and B is married to Y, who is X's mother.  Say that B dies without children, and Y comes to A for either *yibum* or *chalitzah*.  The *gemara* says that as a stringency, we do not allow A to perform *yibum* or *chalitzah* with Y. However, Y is now allowed to go marry C, another man who is not forbidden to her.  If we really should have compared the group of women to a man's brother's wife and not to a man's wife's sister, do we not now have a situation where Y and C might be in an adulterous relationship, as Y wasn't properly cleared from her previous marriage to B?

---

Note: Many of the unqualified statements in this question should be qualified, but for the sake of trimming an already long question, I left out the qualifications.

Comment: I suspect the answer is that the principal of Lechumra Makshinan is a rule about how to decide between options in a Hekesh, not just Safek Lechumra. See other instances of it on [Kiddushin 68a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=20&daf=68&format=pdf) and [Shabbat 83b](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=2&daf=83b&format=pdf).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested in one of the comments, the Gemara is describing an exegetical rule, rather than a principle of erring to the side of stringency when in doubt. This understanding is supported by the gemara's alternative answer there:

איבעית אימא הכא תרי איסורי והכא תרי איסורי ותרי מתרי ילפינן אבל הכא חדא איסורא ותרי מחדא לא ילפינן

*If you prefer, however, I might say: In the former
cases there are two prohibitions in the one as well as in the other, and a double prohibition may
justly be inferred from a double prohibition; in the latter case, however, only one prohibition is
involved, and a double prohibition may not be inferred from a single one.*

This answer is clearly a rule that is used by an ambiguous *hekesh*, and presumably these 2 answers are not miles apart.

It is possible that the **source** for this rule is the principle that when in doubt we follow the stringent ruling, but once written in the "Drasha rule book," it is simply a guideline for figuring out what the pasuk is teaching us.

Comment: Not everyone agrees that "in doubt we follow the stringent ruling" is a Biblical principle.

Comment: @DoubleAA למ"ד ספק דאורייתא לחומרא דאורייתא, אפשר שיש לומר וכו' (I think was the intent of that last paragraph)

Comment: @ShmuelWise Interesting idea. So the "_hekesh_ rule" might be that we follow the local stringency, even if it's not a global stringency.

Comment: @magicker72 ya, I think it makes sense that for the purpose of such a rule, we go by the actual revelation of the pasuk; not its resultant ramifications.